# Sending cookies in js fetch POST or GET request cross server cors enabled server

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, fetch-api

Bellow code references and request references have comments these were added in SO to explain my understanding original requests and code contain no comments.

I am aware of the standard of using auth headers for fetch requests. what I need to do is get the cookie that server A sets to server B without having to pass it via javascript.

I have Server A: http://127.0.0.1:8080 
contains index.html

index.html when cookie jar is looked at contains a cookie [image: cookie details]

I also have Server B: http://0.0.0.0:8081. <- duno if relevant port and ip are different

http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html makes the bellow request

```
let url = "http://0.0.0.0:8081/write" //this url is o a different server so certain headers are needed

  let cookies = document.cookie
  console.log(cookies) //this logs the cookie so I know its defo there
  let otherPram= {
    credentials: 'include',   //this is what I need to tell the browser to include cookies
    method: "GET"

  };

  fetch(url, otherPram)
```

After the request is made the browser makes an options call to http://0.0.0.0:8081/write with response:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: accept, authorization, content-type, origin, x-requested-with, access-control-allow-credentials, cookie, access-control-allow-origin
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1. //also tried this with http://127.0.0.1:8080
access-control-expose-headers: Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, cookie
access-control-max-age: 600
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0
date: Thu, 16 Jan 2020 08:22:19 GMT
```

however the request contains no cookies.

to the best of my knowledge it should send the cookies with the fetch request.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies belong to an origin.

> ```
>   let cookies = document.cookie
>   console.log(cookies) //this logs the cookie so I know its defo there
> ```

That shows that there are cookies for the origin of the HTML document.

> After the request is made the browser makes an options call to http://0.0.0.0:8081/write

So you are making a cross-origin request.

The cookies do not belong to that origin so the browser will not send them.

---

If you want to send cookies to http://0.0.0.0:8081/, then you need to make a request to http://0.0.0.0:8081/ and have it use a `Set-Cookie` header in the response to set them in the first place. The browser won't set the cookies from `:8080` to `:8081` because they aren't `:8081`'s cookies.

---

Typically web services will use [an `Authorization` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) **instead** of cookies.

```
  let otherPram= {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer SomeToken"
    },
    credentials: 'include',   //this is what I need to tell the browser to include cookies
    method: "GET"
  };
```

---

Aside: I removed `"content-type": "application/json"`. You are making a **GET** request so the request has no content to specify the type of.

Comment: all over the auth thing but I don't want to send it in the auth header I want it to passively go with the fetch request the all POST, GET and href page changes can be secured without exposing the key in JS. I would like to set httponly and secure to true this what I am after. is that not what credentials: 'include' does?

Comment: @abe — `credentials: 'include'` means (among a few other things) that cookies will be included … but only cookies that would be sent to the URL, not cookies from the URL of the HTML document.  If you don't want to use an Authorization header, then do what I said in the second second of the answer and make a request to `:8081` which causes the cookies to be set.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand that bit are you saying I need to change the response of the option to say  "Set-Cookie: true"

Comment: No. You need to make a completely separate *request* (probably using POST), containing credentials, to a URL on `:8081` to which the server will respond with `Set-Cookie` headers which sets the same kind of cookie you are using on `:8080` (the response body can be something like "You are now logged in with a cookie on :8081`).

Comment: the problem is 8081 does not have the cookie, my goal is to get the cookie to 8081. Are you saying I need to get 8080 to set cookie then make a request to 8081 that sets cookie to garbage then on success get 8080 to fill it again with right cookie which can then be sent to 8081?

Comment: I'm saying that the cookies for `:8080` and `:8081` are **completely independent** and will never meet, so if you want to do authentication with cookies on `:8081` then you need to make a request to authenticate yourself to `:8081` and set a cookie in the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206060/discussion-between-abe-and-quentin).

Comment: here it says its possible: https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @abe — No, they don't. They agree with me.

Comment: Quote "Now fetch sends cookies originating from another.com without request to that site.". It says "another.com" (the URL passed to fetch) not "javascript.info" (the URL specified in Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: sorry I think I am completely mis understanding you. can I get cookie sent from server 8080 sent to server 8081 if your answer is no then please change your response to say it can't be done if it can be done please be clearer on how it can be done. I will remove the json header so and add comment about auth headers so it does not confuse what you are saying

Comment: Ok I have modified my question to remove the JSON header and added a line at the start to acknowledge the standard of using auth headers. if you could please respond with amore explicit answer to the question of getting cookie from server A to Server B that would rock

Comment: @abe — I thought "The cookies do not belong to that origin so the browser will not send them." was very explicit.

Comment: fair enough. The impression I get from reading online is I can accomplish what I am after. You are probably right and I am misunderstanding what the sites are saying. However I will continue trying and hoping some one else will respond. Apologies for any frustration I have caused you.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting on the server at least with sub domains you can share cookies which is enough in this case.

Along with all the cors properties and the fetch include. The cookie being set needs the domain to be set too.

```
Set-Cookie: myCookie=value; domain=root.com
```

All subdomains of root.com will share that specific cookie.